# sort with two element in list of tuple in python3

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

```
[('sara', 75, 180), ('marko', 90, 190), ('jaimi', 75, 175), ('alex', 60, 175)]
```

I want to sort this list based on height and weight. The second element of each tuple is weight and the third is height.

Task: First sort by height (tall to short). If some element's height is equal sort that element with weight (slim to fat).

The output should be like this:

```
[('marko', 90, 190), ('sara', 75, 180), ('alex', 60, 175), ('jaimi', 75, 175)]
```

I still doing this code:

```
x=sorted(result,key=lambda x: (x[2],x[1]),reverse=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. It's helpful to mention specific problems, like in this case, it looks like your code not sorting properly.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of specifying `reverse=True`, you can change the sign of the height to have the ordering both in descending and ascending order respectively:

```
sorted(result, key=lambda x: (-x[2], x[1]))
# [('marko', 90, 190), ('sara', 75, 180), ('alex', 60, 175), ('jaimi', 75, 175)]
```

Comment: Keeping `reverse` if fine with changing the sign of `x[1]`: `sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[2], -x[1]), reverse=True)`

Comment: Yes it's the same but less code @heemayl